# Socket apparently not working on Raspberrypi 4?

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi4

i am currently trying to make a personal assistant in python and for that i need two python programs to communicate...
here's my code which works fine on Windows 10 pro 1909 and python 3.8

```
import socket

DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"
HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
SERVER = "190.168.172.36"
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)

def send(msg):
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(ADDR)

    message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
    msg_length = len(message)
    send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
    send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
    client.send(send_length)
    client.send(message)
    print(client.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))
    
send("test")
```

however this doesnt work on my raspberrypi 4 4gb with the raspberrypi OS.

when i run the program there is no error and no reaction at all, but the program is running

Comment: Perhaps a firewall is blocking the traffic?

Comment: That's the client side.  What is the server side?

Comment: Well, run it in a debugger, or at least stick in some `print`s so you can see exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem thanks to @jrd1.
The firewall on my Pi was already turned off but not on my windows device.
Thanks again for you help @jrd1!